# Altium power net vs. normal net

Tags: altium

I am a bit confused when we should use power net in the schematic capture versus a normal net.

For example, if I place a 3V3, I would use a power net, however I see sometimes some schematic where some net/node for tension consideration which are placed with normal net.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really depend on the type of the net but more on your project type. For a "normal" project which is usually a hierarchical type, your power nets will be global (across all schematic sheets) whereas net labels are only local. This helps with quickly deciding if a net is used in multiple sheets or only the one you are currently looking at. This can be changed in the Project options -> Options dialog, but usually this is set to "Automatic".

[image: Project Options setting (see red section)]

Comment: my project is currently in a mode of Automatic. WhatI want is all the net to be global (I have only 17 sheets)

Comment: No, you certainly don't want that. You want to connect all signals which go outside a sheet to another sheet using ports, harnesses, .. whatever Altium provides. Making all signals global will lead to total chaos - don't go there.

Comment: so you just separate local net and global net in two categories? is it ?

Comment: I don't understand why it would create total chaos ??!

Comment: Because unless you are very disciplined with your net names, you can have accidental connections made in unrelated sheets. Very bad.

Comment: I wouldn't consider them categories. They are just different scopes. And regarding why: Daniel explained this. Think of a net ERROR_LED. Believe me, you don't want to connect ERROR_LED from your FPGA to ERROR_LED of your controller (which could happen because the net name is the same but the parts are on different sheets) - and this is just an example.

Comment: I am not on FPGA at the moment , just on MCU but I mostly understand your points. I have always used only net so far.I make several review everytime I do a schematic to verify at least visually that two nets don't have the same name.

Comment: Then even more: Let Altium help you, no need to do this manually. Plus, you get a structure where you see how your components depend on each other once you use the hierarchical design.

Comment: I have made a flat design

Answer (score 0):

I assume that net +VDD_SNVS_CAP only connects between IC pin G9 and C143 - if so, it should be a "normal" net.  Just because the net name "looks like" a power net name, doesn't mean that it is really a global power net.

The +3V3 will, I assume, be connected to many things throughout your design, so should be a Global Power net.

Comment: So, as I understand you use POWER NET only for power who are global, is it ?